# How do I deny access to a specific URL in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, apache

I have a rails app that has a private component and a public component.

www.hostname.com/ is private and should only be accessed from inside our firewall, but i want to allow access to www.hostname.com/public to internet users. I played around with the apache vhost config but it seems when I allow access to www.hostname.com it allows all the paths below it as well. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your web root (/var/www)  create this .htaccess file:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
allow from 192.168.0.0/24
```

In your public folder (/var/www/public) create a new .htaccess folder that contains this line:

```
allow from all
```

Make sure .htaccess overrides is enabled in your apache/vhost configs,  this should be enabled by default.